# Why does doctest fail with string containing UTF-8 chars?

Tags: python, html, utf-8, doctest

I'm reading a plain ASCII html file (charset=utf-8) containing this string:

> <title>Whatâ€™s New?</title>

This string is unusable as it is so I came up with this function (to be used after the string has been hexlify'd). Then, I included a docstring test:

```
def to_be_replaced(reprString):
    """
    :reprString: a repr(string) -- won't work otherwise

    >>> s = "<title>Whatâ€™s New?</title>"
    >>> r = repr(s)
    >>> print r
    <title>What\xe2\x80\x99s New?</title>
    >>> to_be_replaced(r)
    set(['\xe2\x80\x99'])
    """
    regex = re.compile('([\x7f-\xff]{2,})')
    return set(re.findall(regex, reprString))
```

Unfortunately, the test fails:

```
>"E:\Python27\pythonw.exe" -u "test_to_be_replaced.py"

to be replaced: set(['\xe2\x80\x99'])

**********************************************************************
File "test_to_be_replaced.py", line 14, in __main__.to_be_replaced
Failed example:
    print r
Expected:
    <title>Whatâ€™s New?</title>
Got:
    '<title>What\xe2\x80\x99s New?</title>'
**********************************************************************
File "test_to_be_replaced.py", line 16, in __main__.to_be_replaced
Failed example:
    to_be_replaced(r)
Expected:
    set(['â€™'])
Got:
    set([])
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   2 of   4 in __main__.to_be_replaced
***Test Failed*** 2 failures.
>Exit code: 0
```

The output above from running:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = '<title>What\xe2\x80\x99s New?</title>'
    print 'to be replaced:', to_be_replaced(s)  # works as intended
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

What can I do in order to make the test pass?

Using python 2.7.10 on Windows 7 x32.